# Atualizar função penas uma vez ao carregar

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte script:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function update() {
  for($i=0;$i<300;$i++){ // a cada 300x (5min) faz um refresh
      atualizaLeilao();
      await sleep(1000);
  }
 location.reload(); 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    update();
});
```

A função **atualizaLeilao()** retorna um status que é definido como: **leilao_status**

Existem os status 1, 2 e 3. Sabendo os status fiz o seguinte:

```
if (leilao_status == 3) {

**AQUI A FUNÇÃO NOVA.**

}else{

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function update() {
  for($i=0;$i<300;$i++){ // a cada 300x (5min) faz um refresh
      atualizaLeilao();
      await sleep(1000);
  }
 location.reload(); 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    update();
});

}
```

No caso para o status = 3, eu preciso que ele execute a função **atualizaLeilao()** apenas uma vez, ou seja, quando a página é carregada ou quando ela é atualizada.

O problema é que para pegar o status é preciso executar a função **atualizaLeilao()**  antes, sem executar a função antes não tem como saber o status.

Como posso fazer ele buscar o status antes em seguida executar as funções de acordo com as regras?

---

Tentei dessa forma:

```
function atualizaLeilao(){
    var leiloes = '';
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $('.itemLeiao').each(function () {
        var auctionId = $(this).attr('title');
        if (leiloes != '') leiloes = leiloes + ',';
        leiloes = leiloes + auctionId;
    });
    if(leiloes){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'leiloes=' + leiloes,
            global: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (j, item) {
                    var leilao_id = item.leilao.id_leilao;
                    var leilao_status = item.leilao.status;

            });
            },
        });        
  }
 }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    atualizaLeilao();
    });



    if (leilao_status == 3) {

    $(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval('atualizaLeilao()', 300);
    atualizaLeilao();
    });

    } else {

    function sleep(ms) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
    async function update() {
      for($i=0;$i<300;$i++){ // a cada 300x (5min) faz um refresh
          atualizaLeilao();
          await sleep(1000);
      }
     location.reload(); 
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        update();
    });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Faz um `return leilao_status;` na função `atualizaLeilao()`, algo assim:

```
function atualizaLeilao(){
   leilao_status = 3;
   return leilao_status;
}
```

E no `if`, você compara se o retorno da função é `3`:

```
if (atualizaLeilao() == 3) {

**AQUI A FUNÇÃO NOVA.**

}else{

...

}
```

### Edit

Mas para que o valor retornado da função seja repetidas vezes comparado, você pode incluir o código numa função. Esse `if` "solto" só irá fazer a comparação 1 vez no carregamento da página. Então o código ficaria assim:

```
function atualizaLeilao(){
    var leilao_status = item.leilao.status;
    return leilao_status;
}

function checa(){
   if (atualizaLeilao() == 3) {

      var tempo = setInterval('checa()', 300);

   }else{

      clearInterval(tempo);

      function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
      }
      async function update() {
        for($i=0;$i<300;$i++){ // a cada 300x (5min) faz um refresh
            atualizaLeilao();
            await sleep(1000);
        }
       location.reload(); 
      }

       update();

   }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   checa();
});
```

Comment: Não funcionou, eu atualizei a pergunta com a forma que eu tentei fazer.

Comment: Ele até funcionou, carregou a função, mas não obedeceu as regras, não ficou atualizando de acordo com o status.

Comment: Se tiver com status 2 ou 1 ele pode alterar a qualquer momento, mas se já carregar com o status 3 ele não vai alterar.

Comment: Coloquei tudo numa função, veja: https://jsfiddle.net/48owsy99/4/

Comment: Ixi, não ta funcionando não. :/ Atualizei a pergunta com uma parte mais completa da função atualizaLeilao()

Comment: Vc tá querendo ver o status de vários items com o Ajax ou espera receber apenas um?

Comment: Quando acessa um item em uma página, ele carrega esse JS com os dados daquele item. Cada item pode ter um status diferente. Além do status ele pega outras informações também, que não coloquei ali.

Comment: Atualizei o Fiddle. Porque é o seguinte: ao chamar a função que retorna o Ajax, o retorno não é imediato, aí tem que usar um callback .then... Veja o código: https://jsfiddle.net/48owsy99/8/

Answer (score 0):

tente executar a função **atualizaLeilao** logo quando o programa carregar, para isso faça algo como:

```
(function()){
    atualizaLeilao();
}());
```

Com isso o programa executará a função sem que ela precise ser chamada, assim deverá retornar um status.

Comment: Nao funcionou. Eu atualizei a pergunta com uma forma que eu tentei, quase deu certo.

Comment: Carregou a função, mas não obedeceu as regras, não ficou atualizando de acordo com o status

Comment: oh, vc nao pode definir uma variável fixa dentro da função, ao criar um var leilao_status vc faz com que a variável exista somente enquanto a função é executada, crie-a por fora (sem valor) e dentro da função remova o var, de modo a somente atualizar seu valor

Comment: Hum, tentei tirar o var mas não funcionou também, criei ela dentro da função, sem sucesso.